# How do I keep asking the user for a double input till the user enters a blank line?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, user-input

I want this program to ask for values and keep feeding them into the `addCoefficient` method (not shown). If a user enters a non double value, it should say `Invalid input`, which is working. The user can input a maximum of 10 values or enter a blank line to save less than 10. I cannot get it to stop accepting values when a blank line is entered. How would I go about this? Here's what I have so far:

```
System.out.println("Type in the polynomials in increasing powers.");
        Scanner prompt = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            while (!(prompt.hasNextDouble())) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                prompt.next();
            }
            expression.addCoefficient(prompt.nextDouble());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        while(true)
        {
            String entry = in.nextLine();
            if( entry.equals("") )
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
```

Explanation: `Scanner.nextLine()` consumes the line and removes the newline char `\n`. If the user inputs a blank enter, it'll read the string as empty `""` and if they enter something else it'll be `"3.5"` for example. Then you can try/catch a cast to double to check for your invalid inputs.

Another valid solution would be to use `break ;` inside the forloop when its the empty line, and iterate 0 to 10 exclusive still.

Comment: I tried an if-else statement with `break;` if the input is `""` but it still is not working as expected. From all the testing I've done it seems like hitting enter just doesn't count as an input and it keeps letting me put in numbers till the loop runs out.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the reply till now; it should go until you press enter twice in a row if that makes sense. Basically entering a blank line. Not sure

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to answer this question but it should be something like this:

```
        System.out.println("Type in the polynomials in increasing powers.");
        Scanner prompt = new Scanner(System.in);
        String badNumber = null;
        Double goodNumber = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            while (!(badNumber = prompt.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    goodNumber = Double.parseDouble(badNumber);
                    expression.addCoefficient(goodNumber);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Please insert a valid number");
                }
            }
        }
```